# Laravel blade pass variable to php function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

```
   function GetIpData($ip){
        $remoteData = 'http://api.ipstack.com/'.$ip.'?access_key=xxxxxxxxxxxx';
        $fData = file_get_contents($remoteData);

        $jdata =  json_decode($fData);
        $country_name  = $jdata->country_name;
        $region_name   = $jdata->region_name;

        return $country_name.'<br>'.$region_name;
    }
    
    
    <td class="center aligned">{{ $user->last_login_ip }}<br>{!! GetIpData($user->last_login_ip) !!}</td>
```

I like to pass an ip address to the function `GetIpData($ip)` defined in `helpers.php`
If i pass an ip direct, it works

```
<td class="center aligned">{{ $user->last_login_ip }}<br>{!! GetIpData('223.204.248.45') !!}</td>
```

but i get it not to run by using the variable `$user->last_login_ip`

Comment: Did you `{{ dd($user->last_login_ip) }}` to see what it contains? Maybe add some validation/error handling inside `GetIpData`